# Why does error 9 occur when assigning a value to an array?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to assign some accumulated values to an array, but the following error occurs:

> Subscript out of range (error 9).

Here's the code:

```
Dim array1(), acm As Long
Dim i As Integer

i = 0
For lin = 4 To contRows 
    For col = 3 To contColumns
       acm = acm + Sheets("2017").Cells(lin, col).Value
    Next col
    array1(i) = acm 'error 9
    i = i + 1
Next lin
```

I'm expecting to have each accumulated value from that row be stored in a different array index.

Comment: What happens if you `dim` `i` as `long`?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad tried it and it shows the same error

Comment: You never give `array` dimensions.  You need either need to `ReDim` it to give it appropriate dimensions, or you need to include its dimensions in the original `Dim` line.  Otherwise it's an array that can't hold any elements, and therefore any position in the array will be invalid (hence "out of range").  It looks like what you want, after the `Dim array1()...` line is `ReDim array1(1 to contRows - 3)`

Comment: It worked, just had to change it to `ReDim array1(0 To contRows - 4)` becasue it didn't work initially. Thanks!!

Comment: @tigeravatar Why didn't you give this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(copied from tigeravatar)

You never give `array` dimensions. You need either need to `ReDim` it to give it appropriate dimensions, or you need to include its dimensions in the original `Dim` line. Otherwise it's an array that can't hold any elements, and therefore any position in the array will be invalid (hence "out of range"). It looks like what you want, after the `Dim array1()...` line is `ReDim array1(1 to contRows - 3)`